# System function overloading in nested shared library

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, ld, dynamic-linking

### Simple scenario

1. Application uses `write` function from `libc` and links to shared library.
2. Shared library defines `write` function.
3. Original `write` function from `libc` will be overloaded by its version from the shared library.

### Nested scenario

1. Application uses `write` function from `libc`.
2. Shared library 1 does not defines its own `write` but depends on shared library 2.
3. Shared library 2 defines `write` function.
4. No. `write` function will *NOT* be replaced with a version from the second shared library.

I do want to understand Why so ? How to make it work with nested shared library dependencies.

Here is exact code examples:

main.c

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

    write(1,"Hello\n",6);
    return 0;
}
```

shared-lib-1.c

```
#include <unistd.h>

__attribute__((constructor))
void shared_lib_1_constructor(void) {
    char str[] = "shared-lib-1-constructor\n";
    write(1, str, sizeof(str)); 
}
```

shared-lib-2.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count) {
    exit(1);
    return 0;
}

__attribute__((constructor))
void shared_lib_2_constructor(void) {
    char str[] = "shared-lib-2-constructor\n";
    write(1, str, sizeof(str)); 
}
```

build.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

set -v
set -e

gcc -g -fPIC -shared shared-lib-2.c -o libshared-lib-2.so
gcc -g -fPIC -shared -Wl,-rpath . -L`pwd` -lshared-lib-2 shared-lib-1.c -o libshared-lib-1.so
gcc -g -L`pwd` -Wl,-rpath . -lshared-lib-1 main.c
```

Execution of the `a.out` gives:

```
[smirnov@localhost tmp]$ ./a.out 
shared-lib-2-constructor
shared-lib-1-constructor
Hello
```

`write` was not overwritten by shared-lib-2. It was completely ignored even from shared-lib-2 code.

How does it work with nested libraries ? Moving `write` definition to shared-lib-1 *does* work, it overloads `glibc` version and exits from application.

Running application with `LD_DEBUG=all` shows order of resolving:

```
   36441:     Initial object scopes
   36441:     object=./a.out [0]
   36441:      scope 0: ./a.out ./libshared-lib-1.so /lib64/libc.so.6 ./libshared-lib-2.so /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
...
   36441:     calling init: ./libshared-lib-2.so
   36441:     
   36441:     symbol=write;  lookup in file=./a.out [0]
   36441:     symbol=write;  lookup in file=./libshared-lib-1.so [0]
   36441:     symbol=write;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
   36441:     binding file ./libshared-lib-2.so [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `write'
```

Why `libc` placed in between shared-lib-1 and shared-lib-2 ?
It seems that `ld` resolves in the following order:

- all dependencies of a.out, but not recursivelly, only first level
- all subdependencies, but not recursivelly
- so on...

The only solution I've found is to use

```
LD_DYNAMIC_WEAK=1 ./a.out
```

Is there a way to fix behavior in advance ?

Answer (score 0):

> `write` function will NOT be replaced with a version from the second shared library.

This is not what I expected, and it took me a while to figure out why it's happening.

The issue is that `libc.so.6` doesn't define `write` function (if it did, everything would have worked the same whether the dependency is direct or not).

Instead, `libc.so.6` defines a *versioned* `write@@GLIBC_2.2.5` symbol. It is that symbol versioning (a GNU extension) which interferes with your desired outcome.

Compare:

```
gcc main.c ./libshared-lib-1.so && nm -D a.out | grep ' write'
                 U write@GLIBC_2.2.5
gcc main.c ./libshared-lib-2.so && nm -D a.out | grep ' write'
                 U write
```

When performing symbol resolution, the loader looks up symbol version in the search scope (and `a.out` is at the front). With `libshared-lib-1.so`, the loader finds that it should be looking for `write` version `GLIBC_2.2.5` (which can only be found in `libc.so.6`), and ignores the un-versioned definition in `libshared-lib-2.so`.

> Is there a way to fix behavior in advance ?

If you can control the application link line, it's best to link `a.out` with `libshared-lib-2.so`:

```
gcc main.c ./libshared-lib-1.so ./libshared-lib-2.so
./a.out
# no output as expected.
```

If you can't control the application link line, you should be able to provide a versioned `write@GLIBC_2.2.5` using the linker `--version-script` flag and appropriate version script. But my initial attempt at doing that failed, and I am not sure this approach can be made to work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm not sure if it solves the issue.
`nm a.out | fgrep write` gives `U write@@GLIBC_2.2.5`
`nm libshared-lib-1.so | fgrep write` gives `U write`
`nm libshared-lib-2.so | fgrep write` gives `U write`

As I stated in the question - order of resolution is `a.out -> shared-lib-1 -> libc -> shared-lib-2`

I believe that with this order `write` version in shared-lib-2 will have nothing to do with the final decision.

I don't have control over application link line and main question is there way to alter current behavior with nested links, not direct.

Comment: Your last example works not because of version of `write`, but because of final order of resolution altered and `libc` placed on the last position. You can check it with `LD_DEBUG=all`